# Match all characters and line breaks up to the ", ^" characters

Tags: regex

So I am trying to match a string like

```
Blah, blah, whatever 
etc. , ^
```

I want to grab everything before , `^` like

```
Blah, blah, whatever 
etc.
```

I tried

```
(.*?), \^'
```

But this fails on strings with line breaks.

How do I get line breaks matching in the capture group as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
^(?:(?! *, *\^)[\s\S])*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF5qI5/10)

**Breakup**

```
(?! *, *\^) # negative lookahead that fails the match if next pattern is 0 or more spaces
            # followed by a comma and optional spaces and literal ^
[\s\S]      # matches any character including newlines
```

Comment: Note that they want to match until `, ^`, which rules out the simple negation and would require a lookahead.

Comment: Yes, what Joey said.  I don't really understand lookaheads though.

Comment: @humanbeing: Check my edited answer. Yes I slightly misread due to non formatted question earlier. `^((?! *, \^)[\s\S])*` will give you your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use single-line mode. Turn it on by prefixing your regex with `(?s)`. This makes the dot match all characters *including* line breaks:

```
PS> [regex]::Match($s, '(.*?), \^').Value
etc. , ^
PS> [regex]::Match($s, '(?s)(.*?), \^').Value
Blah, blah, whatever
etc. , ^
```

In some languages you may need to (or can) give additional options to the regex as additional method arguments or they are suffixed to the regex literal, if there is one.