# Using REGEX for field validation

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro with multiple sheet and multiple validations. One of the requirement is to limit 1000 characters in range of cells. You are allowed to enter any character. 
I am achieving it through regex. My code reads as -----> Public Const QUAL_REGEX = "^.{1,1000}$"

I also have an error handling if the above condition s not met. For e.g. if the length exceeds 1000 characters. 
This works fine. However, it gives an error when there is line break or enter character. I want to allow users to be able to use enter or line breaks. How can I achieve using REGEX.

Comment: you can check the cell value length instead : `IF Len(cell.Value) > 1000 Then`

Comment: You can try this negative lookahead based regex:similiar to `^(?:(?! *, *\^)[\s\S])*` Further `(?! *, *\^) # negative lookahead that fails the match if next pattern is 0 or more spaces
            # followed by a comma and optional spaces and literal ^
[\s\S]      # matches any character including newlines. As explained in the SO Link<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785808/match-all-characters-and-line-breaks-up-to-the-characters>

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, in VBScript Regex, `dot` does not match `newline`.  To get around that in a Regex, try `"^[\s\S]{1,1000}$"`

Note that this would be the same as if you just tested that the length of the entry was in the range of `1-1000`, and would not involve the extra overhead of the Regular Expression engine.